# How do I raise the value of counter if there is random number generated?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, random

So basically, I have an array with 50 random numbers and I want to raise the number of count if I get the same random number. After all that counting I want to see how often I got which number but I seem to have a error in my counting method. So it basically gives me, for example, more zeros than there are in random generated numbers.

This is my program code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class aufgabe2 {

  static int[] ran = new int[50];
  static int[] counter = new int[10];

  static Random r = new Random();

  public static void ranNums() {
    for (int i = 0; i < ran.length; i++) {
      ran[i] = r.nextInt(10);
      System.out.print(ran[i] + " ");
    }
  }

  public static void countSameRanNums(int[] counter) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      counter[ran[i]]++;
      System.out.println(i + ".frequency: " + (counter[ran[i]]));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ranNums();
    countSameRanNums(ran);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, `ran` is an array of 50 values, but you're only iterating the first 9.

Comment: I guess he want to generate from 0-9 for 50 times and get the frequency of 0-9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you have it is that you are only iterating the first 9 positions of ran array, that has 50 positions.

Furthermore, I think you do not need two methods to get the count of each random number. You can count them at the same time you get the random values. Look at this:

```
public static void ranNums() {
   for (int i = 0; i < ran.length; i++) {
      ran[i] = r.nextInt(10);
      System.out.print(ran[i] + " ");
      counter[ran[i]]++;
   }
}
```

And after you only have to make a loop to get all the counts:

```
for(int j = 0; j < counter.length; j++)
{
    System.out.println(j + ".frequency: " + (counter[j]));
}
```

Comment: This worked out, thanks a lot for helping me, and understanding my problem it probably was not that easy because of my weak english. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class aufgabe2 { 
static int[] ran = new int[50];
static int[] counter = new int[10];

static Random r = new Random();

public static void ranNums() {
int counter;
Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < ran.length; i++) {
    counter = 1;
    ran[i] = r.nextInt(10);
    if(map.containsKey(ran[i])){
        map.put(ran[i], map.get(ran[i])+1);
    } else {
        map.put(ran[i], counter);
    }
}

    Iterator<?> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " frequency : " + pair.getValue());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ranNums();
   }
}
```

Let me know if you need anything above to be explained

Comment: This worked but it is really complex, and I dont know what Map, HashMap and Iterator are yet, because I am pretty new to Java but thanks a lot for your help aswell, and I dont think you have to explain it, but thanks for showing a diffrent Method of solving the problem.

Comment: I can only accept one answer somehow, I am pretty new to the forum, I am sorry I wanted to accept both.